# New nexus 7 tablet locks rotation - any way to reset without a reboot?

Tags: nexus-7, 4.4-kitkat, screen, tablet, auto-rotation

Since I updated my nexus 7 2013 to Android 4.4.2 I have an issue where my screen rotation is locked without any way to return it to normal (even after turning on/off the auto lock feature).  Not sure if this is happening to a lot of people out there,  but the only way to fix it is to turn the tablet off for a few seconds and turn it back on. My question is, is there a way to reset the rotation from a software perspective? Is There any service that I can start and stop. I need to make sure this is not hardware related and that possibly the best way to test it.

Comment: You say in your question that you tried turning on/off the auto lock feature. What exact steps did you take?

Comment: Drop down the right menu from the top of the screen,  then disabling "auto rotate",  wait a few moments while moving the screen in different directions, and the enabling "auto rotate" again.

Comment: Did you make sure that screen rotation isn't an issue with the ROM? Sometimes reflashing the ROM will correct that issue. It isn't a hardware though. You can also flash a different ROM altogether if the 4.4.2 still doesn't auto rotate the screen. Just make sure you check all settings, might be something you overlooked. By the way stock or custom 4.4.2?

Comment: For what is worth, I recently moved to Cyanogenmod's latest release and it still behaves the same way. When i reboot the device, once in a while it works but eventually it breaks and I have to use the app to switch the screen. I'm starting to think is a issue in the core-android code. It is so annoying!

Answer (score 2):

Rebooting into `Safe Mode` fixed the issue for me somehow.

To go boot into `Safe Mode`:

> 1) Long Press on the power button for 1 second.
>
> 2) in the power off menu that appears, press and hold the Power Off option.
>
> 3) A Reboot into Safe Mode dialog will appear, Click Ok to boot into safe mode.

After you have booted once into safe mode, check if your auto rotation is working. If it is working then good, reboot normally. If not, then it is most likely a hardware issue and get your nexus 7 replaced/repaired by Asus.

Answer (score 1):

I use an android app called Adaptive Rotation.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ui.robot.rotate

It adds the ability to rotate the screen in any orientation and it STAYS that way. So when apps want to rotate your screen and you want it in Landscape, it stays in landscape, or whatever your preferred orientation is.

As its software it should fix your issue.

Comment: This has not fixed the problem but it has made the experience livable.